# Limpiar un datetimepicker de tempusdominus Boostrap 4 Jquery

Tags: jquery, datetime, momentjs, datetimepicker

Tengo un problema al intentar limpiar un datetimepicker de TempusDominus
tengo una funcion la cual inizializa mi datatimepicker y le entrego un minDate y un maxDate dependiendo del valor de 2 input.

los 2 input obtienen su valor de un select el cual me trae una fecha inicial y una fecha de termino los cuales son los valores que le asigno al minDate y maxDate.

La funcion la activo al darle al btn "btnSiguiente" con un `setTimeout(dateCalendar,100);`
pero necesito que al apretar el btn "btnAtras" se limpie el minDate y maxDate, ya que estos dependen de los input antes mencionados.

esta es mi funcion la cual contiene el datetimepicker

```
var dateCalendar = function(){
  var dateFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY";
  var MinDate = $('#fecha_inicio_curso').val();
  var MaxDate = $('#fecha_termino_curso').val();

  dateMin = moment(MinDate, dateFormat);
  dateMax = moment(MaxDate, dateFormat);

  $(".date").datetimepicker({
    locale: 'es',
    format: dateFormat,
    minDate: dateMin,
    maxDate: dateMax,
  });
}
```

esta la activo al dar click en el "btnSiguiente"

```
$("#btnSiguiente").click(function(){
  $('#modal-alumno').modal('hide');
  setTimeout("$('#modal-horario-practico').modal('show')", 100);
  setTimeout(dateCalendar,100);
});
```

y esto es lo que intente al dar click en el "btnAtras"

(Tambien intente buscar algun metodo similar al *destroy()* de datepicker, pero no me funciono, me da error de que la función no existe)

```
$("#btnAtras").click(function(){
  $('#modal-horario-practico').modal('hide');
  setTimeout("$('#modal-alumno').modal('show')", 100);
  $('#fecha_clase_0').datetimepicker({
    minDate: null, // tambien intente con 'false'
    maxDate: null
  });
  $('#fecha_clase').datetimepicker("clear"); // da error
})
```

pero no pasa nada al apretar el btnAtras.

Esta es la forma en que entrego los valores a los input mediante el select2

```
$('#cursos').on("select2:selecting", function(e) {
  $('#fecha_inicio_curso').val('');
  $('#fecha_termino_curso').val('');
  var fechasCurso = function(){
    var curso_id = $("#cursos").val();
    var view_html='';
    var url = "{{ url('getFechasCurso') }}/"+curso_id;

    $.get(url, function (r) {
      var data = $.parseJSON(r);
      console.log(data);
      if(data.id_curso>0){

        var fecha_i = data.fecha_inicio;
        var fecha_t = data.fecha_termino;

        var fecha_inicio = fecha_i.replace(/\//g, '-');
        var fecha_termino = fecha_t.replace(/\//g, '-');

        $('#fecha_inicio_curso').val(fecha_inicio);
        $('#fecha_termino_curso').val(fecha_termino);
      }
    });  
  }
  setTimeout(fechasCurso,100);
});
```

intente inicializar el datetimepicker desde esta ultima funcion, para que se inicialice con el nuevo min/maxDate cada vez que cambiara este select2, pero no logre hacerlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUCIONADO**
ya que no me funciono la forma de cambiar a null/false el min/maxDate, busque la forma de hacer un destroy al datetimepicker, y fue de la siguiente manera (en mi "btnAtras")

```
$calendar = $('#fecha_clase_0');
if($calendar.data('datetimepicker')){
  $calendar.data('datetimepicker').destroy();
}
```